# Counter reset next day

Tags: excel, vba, counter, userform

I have to create a form where I need to put a counter of inputs that have to restart the next day and do not reset after the form is closed. All that happens is that the form is counting until it is closed. After I turn it on again it starts from the beginning. NumberBox is where I am looking value to change and do not reset until the next day.

This is my Code

```
Set sf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF")
Dim n As Long

Dim LDate As String
LDate = Format(Now, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm AM/PM")

n = sf.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



sf.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Me.DateBox.Value
sf.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.BatchNameBox.Value + "-" + NumberBox.Value

sf.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Me.OperatorBox.Value
sf.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = Me.BatchVolBox.Value
sf.Range("E" & n + 1).Value = Me.APPAddedBox.Value
sf.Range("F" & n + 1).Value = Me.ZtagAddedBox.Value
sf.Range("G" & n + 1).Value = Me.StartTimeBox.Value
sf.Range("H" & n + 1).Value = Me.EndTimeBox.Value
sf.Range("I" & n + 1).Value = Me.ShootInvBox.Value
sf.Range("J" & n + 1).Value = Me.Vib1Box.Value
sf.Range("K" & n + 1).Value = Me.Vib2Box.Value
sf.Range("L" & n + 1).Value = Me.Vib3Box.Value
sf.Range("M" & n + 1).Value = Me.FlowBox.Value
sf.Range("N" & n + 1).Value = Me.CFPressureBox.Value
sf.Range("O" & n + 1).Value = Me.RecircTimeBox.Value
sf.Range("P" & n + 1).Value = Me.InitialBox.Value
sf.Range("Q" & n + 1).Value = Me.FinalBox.Value
sf.Range("R" & n + 1).Value = Me.RemovedBox.Value
sf.Range("S" & n + 1).Value = Me.CommentsBox.Value

Static cnt As Long
cnt = cnt + 1

Do While Me.BatchNameBox.Value > Me.BatchNameBox.Value
cnt = cnt + 1
Loop


If Me.BatchNameBox.Value > Me.BatchNameBox.Value Then
NumberBox.Value = 1
End If




NumberBox = Val(NumberBox) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub NumberBox_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.DateBox = Now()
```

End of the code

Comment: Store all the values you want to keep in some hidden sheet. Is the only way.

Comment: If all you need is to track a single value - the counter - that can be saved in a Document Property, for example, if you don't want to use a hidden worksheet. Also possible is to save it in a Custom XML Part.

Comment: In one of my macros, I had several small screenshots on a sheet.  I would store different values behind these screenshots.  User's never knew they were there but they were a good place to store data....just like a hidden sheet

Comment: I see you're using the [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement) statement; which maintains for the life of the Application, or until the code is stopped. You can Static a collection and say, keep the last 10 items on it, or whatever. Since you're okay with the variables being destroyed on Close, Static should work well.